# Iterating lists and updating dictionary for corresponding match logic improvement

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, hash-map

I have two lists:

1. **Users** - [`<UserObject1>`, `<UserObject2>`, ...]
2. **Contributions** - [`<ContributionObject1>`, `<ContributionObject2>`, ...]

Every `ContributionObject` further can have single or multiple `UserObject` in it which are mentioned as `person_links` here and both the objects that are `ContributionObject` and `UserObject` has certain methods and attributes.

`UserObject` has an attribute `affiliation`.

I have to check whether `UserObject` from **Users** and have the same `affiliation` to one of the `UserObject` from `ContributionObject` from **Contributions**.

If yes, I have to make a dictionary where `key` will be the `user` from **Users** and `value` will be an array of ceratin `ContributionObject` attributes that is `title` and `url`.

I am able to do it with the following logic.

I wanted to ask if this logic can be improved further?

If there is another efficient way to do this task, do mention that. Thanks for all the help. :)

```py
conflicts = dict()
for user in users:
    if user.affiliation:
        for contribution in contributions:
            if not conflicts.get(user):
                conflicts[user] = [
                    (
                        contribution.title,
                        contribution.url,
                    )
                    for person in contribution.person_links
                    if user.affiliation in person.affiliation
                ]
            else:
                conflicts[user] += [
                    (
                        contribution.title,
                        contribution.url,
                    )
                    for person in contribution.person_links
                    if user.affiliation in person.affiliation
                ]
```

I tried to find out better ways to update dict values on SO but they were mostly about updating the existing values(overriding) not about adding(appending) to an existing value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering DRY principal, this

```
if not conflicts.get(user):
    conflicts[user] = [
                (
                    contribution.title,
                    contribution.url,
                )
                for person in contribution.person_links
                if user.affiliation in person.affiliation
            ]
else:
    conflicts[user] += [
                (
                    contribution.title,
                    contribution.url,
                )
                for person in contribution.person_links
                if user.affiliation in person.affiliation
            ]
```

can and should be replaced with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

conflicts = defaultdict(list)
...
for contribution in contributions:
    conflicts[user].extend((contribution.title, contribution.url)
                           for person in contribution.person_links
                           if user.affiliation in person.affiliation)
```

Or at least take advantage of [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) (while preferring a dict literal over a call to `dict` to save method look-up time):

```
conflicts = {}
...
for contribution in contributions:
    conflicts.setdefault(user, []).extend((contribution.title, contribution.url)
                                          for person in contribution.person_links
                                          if user.affiliation in person.affiliation)
```